# Laravel Nova "CSRF token mismatch." Error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

Hi every one Am using Laravel nova 4 on the login am having the following error when i fill and submit the login form

````
exception: "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\HttpException"
file: "F:\\MAG\\Projet Dev MAG\\GOHZE Project\\Echomoov\\Src\\Account\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler.php"
line: 379
message: "CSRF token mismatch."
```|
Any idea on how to solve this issue
````

Comment: Do you have a CSRF tag on your login form? Usually added with `@csrf` or `csrf_token()`

Comment: Am using laravel nova by default it have it

Comment: @aynber any idea

Answer (score -1):

If you use the application on development environment, you can modify this file

> app/http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php

Add/modify following line with your application url or `'*/*'`

```
protected $except = [
        //
        'http://localapp.test/*',
        '*/*'
        
    ];
```

Hope this can help you solve the problem

Comment: Exempting */* from CSRF checking is ⚠️ *terrible* from security perspective. Even "just nova paths" would be terrible idea since Nova is usually used for admin panels, i.e. its endpoints expose CRUD for the whole DB.